# Envelop id in subject line of powerform (Docusign)

Tags: docusignapi, powerform

I am using docusign with powerform after signing the document user gets the email where envelope id will included within signed pdf document. Can envelope id will be sent via subject line or as text in that email?? How to configure if possibilities are there??

Comment: But why you  want to add envelopeId in the subject or email body, what is the benefit for the signer?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to send envelopeId neither in Subject nor in the email Body.